# Printing all children into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a simple program that stores the amount of formula drank each day.

```
private final String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference feedRecordsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("feedRecords").child(date);
```

As you can see each time I save a record it will save will the date as the child of Feed Records

[image: Firebase]

Annoyingly I've only done one for today hence why there's only one date present

I want to print out each date that appears into a RecyclerView

(afterwards im going to make them clickable to go in and view the records)

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("feedRecords");


    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Records>().setQuery(databaseReference,Records.class).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Records, RecordsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecordsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Records model) {


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecordsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_records_view,viewGroup,false);

            return new RecordsViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I am struggling to find a way to print all the children of feed records into my recyclerView, I believe the code I need is to go into onBindViewHolder

For instance I would like the recyclerview to only populate with 04-02-2019 at the moment, but if I where to add more records in upcoming days it would populate with these days also

I'm struggling to reference this child as it will change daily

Any help is greatly appreciated, if I haven't explained clearly please let me know so I can clarify

Records.java

```
package com.example.lewisthompson.childcareapplication;

public class Records {
public String timestamp;

public Records(){

}

public Records(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

RecordsViewHolder.java

```
package com.example.lewisthompson.childcareapplication;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecordsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView t1;

public RecordsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_date);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you bind data in `onBindViewHolder` from `Records`  model to `RecordsViewHolder`

Comment: I cant seem to get it to reference the date in the records model to have it bind

Comment: post the code of `Records` and `RecordsViewHolder`

Comment: What is the expected result in the RecyclerView, only dates?

Comment: That's the two code chunks added in now, and yes alex the result should be dates only, those which are the child of feedRecords